# How to catch errors involving XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to catch all errors with the help of TRY {} CATCH(){} when I send data to a server via XMLHttpRequest.

How can I receive all errors, such as `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`, etc. ?

Comment: Are you using any javascript frameworks such as jQuery or MooTools? If not, maybe consider it as they have success / error handling built into their AJAX functions as well as taking care of cross browser issues etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't like any frameworks. I wanna use pure JS)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Refer this,

```
function createXMLHttpRequestObject()
{
  // xmlHttp will store the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
  var xmlHttp;
  // try to instantiate the native XMLHttpRequest object
  try
  {
    // create an XMLHttpRequest object
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
        try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    catch(e) { }
  }
  // return the created object or display an error message
  if (!xmlHttp)
    alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
  else 
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I'm goonna try it)

Comment: ActiveX works only in Microsoft Browsers!

Answer (score 5):

Try catches didn't work for me. I personally ended up testing for response == "" and status == 0.

```
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("post", VALIDATE_URL, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function receiveResponse() {

            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    console.log("We got a response : " + this.response);
                } else if (!isValid(this.response) && this.status == 0) {
                    console.log("The computer appears to be offline.");
                }
            }
        };
        req.send(payload);
        req = null;
```

Comment: Why do you need to check `isValid()` as well? Doesn't status==0 already mean that the client is offline? I actually seem to have the problem of not catching all offline statuses with just that check.

Comment: I'm not certain that `status == 0` is enough in all cases but feel free to experiment ;)

Comment: I can imagine so too, but by using `&&` you chain `status == 0` to some other condition. So your code says, "status == 0 is enough but we also need another condition to apply as well". This is what I do not understand. In what case does status == 0 not indicate being offline?

Comment: Can you write a definition for `isvalid()` because otherwise you get a *not found error*.

Answer (score -1):

You should put all the statements which you think that will cause an exception in a try block. After that you can give several catch statements - each one for one exception. In last you can give finally as well - this statement will be executed after Try block regardless of whether or not exception was thrown or caught.

Syntax can be like this:

```
try{
try_statements
}

[catch (exception_var_2) { catch_statements_1 }]
[catch (exception_var_2) { catch_statements_2 }]
...
[catch (exception_var_2) { catch_statements_N }]

[finally { finally_statements }]
```

Example:

```
try {
   myroutine(); // may throw three exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof TypeError) {
   // statements to handle TypeError exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof RangeError) {
   // statements to handle RangeError exceptions
} catch (e if e instanceof EvalError) {
   // statements to handle EvalError exceptions
} catch (e) {
   // statements to handle any unspecified exceptions
   logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
}
```

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: This try catch formulation is non-standard and mozilla (Firefox) only.